# SetValue/GetValue vs. directly accessing array via arguments

Tags: vb.net, vb6-migration

I have an array which originally was a Variant array in VB6.

Example code in VB6:

```
ListBoxDrawings.List(X1, Y1) = myArray(X2, Y2)
myArray(A, B) = ListBoxDrawings.List(I, C)
```

After running it through [ArtinSoft's VBUC](http://www.artinsoft.com/pr_vbcompanion.aspx), its values are handled using [`GetValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/147tce02.aspx) & [`SetValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1sefc5x).

Example code in VB.NET: *(ignore conversion to ListView)*

```vb
ListViewDrawings.Items(X1).SubItems(Y1).Text = CStr(myArray.GetValue(X2, Y2))
myArray.SetValue(ListViewDrawings.Items(I).SubItems(C).Text, A, B)
```

Since VB.NET doesn't do Variants, I figured out that the array should be typed as a 2D String Array.  It seems like there's no reason to use GetValue/SetValue, as the former returns an Object and the latter takes one.  This means that I'd have to cast the returned object as a String (Cstr) if I wanted to assign it to a variable, which seems like a pointless extra step that might introduce errors.  Also, since the method has lots of overloads, the code might not be as clear.  **Is there any advantage to using SetValue / GetValue**, or should I just consider that an artifact of VBUC converting a Variant, and access the array directly like the original code did?

VB.NET without Get/Set methods:

```vb
ListViewDrawings.Items(X1).SubItems(Y1).Text = myArray(X2, Y2)
myArray(A, B) = ListViewDrawings.Items(I).SubItems(C).Text
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ditch the Object in favor of String for sure. Conversion tools almost always treat Variants as Object because in VB6 a Variant is the universal type, just as in .NET Object is.

Comment: So I shouldn't bother with the GetValue/SetValue methods, then?

Comment: There is no advantage to GetValue / SetValue and plenty of disadvantages as you pointed out, so use your strongly-typed String array instead.